# NSURLSession TLS Chain Validation not working

Tags: cocoa, nsurlsession

I'm having a problem with networking on my OS X application. It will not be sandboxed. I'm using a data task with NSURLSession to connect to a server who's certificate was created from a self-signed CA per [TN2326](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2326/_index.html). I'm calling it with the URL `https://rc2dev.rc2.io:8443/login` which is mapped  to an internal ip address for a linux vm on my development box.

The url works with both curl and nscurl, so it isn't a server issue. In keychain, I marked my CA as trusted, which is why nscurl works.

I wrapped my code into a wrapper class that isolates the NSURLSession code:

```
public class LoginHandler: NSObject, NSURLSessionDataDelegate {
let urlConfig:NSURLSessionConfiguration
let baseUrl:NSURL
var loggedInHandler:LoginHandler?
var urlSession:NSURLSession!
var loginResponse:NSURLResponse?
var responseData:NSMutableData = NSMutableData()

public typealias LoginHandler = (data:NSData?, response:NSHTTPURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void

init(config:NSURLSessionConfiguration, baseUrl:NSURL) {
    self.urlConfig = config
    self.baseUrl = baseUrl
    super.init()
}

public func login(login:String, password:String, handler:LoginHandler) {
    self.urlSession = NSURLSession(configuration: urlConfig, delegate: self, delegateQueue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
    loggedInHandler = handler
    let url = NSURL(string: "login", relativeToURL: baseUrl)

    let req = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    req.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    req.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
    req.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(["login":login, "password":password], options: [])

    let task = urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(req);
    task.resume()
}

public func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void)
{
    log.info("challenge 1")
    guard challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust,
        let serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust,
        let serverCert = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(serverTrust, 0),
        let certPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("server", withExtension: "cer"),
        let storedData = NSData(contentsOfURL: certPath) where
        storedData.isEqualToData(SecCertificateCopyData(serverCert))  else
    {
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.CancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
        return
    }
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, nil)
}

public func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void)
{
    log.info("challenge 2")
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, nil)
}

public func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionResponseDisposition) -> Void)
{
    self.loginResponse = response
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition.Allow)
}

public func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData)
{
    responseData.appendData(data)
}

public func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?)
{
    if error != nil {
        loggedInHandler!(data: nil, response:loginResponse as! NSHTTPURLResponse!, error: error)
    } else {
        loggedInHandler!(data:responseData, response:loginResponse as! NSHTTPURLResponse!, error:nil)
    }
    urlSession.invalidateAndCancel()
}
```

The only delegate method called is didCompleteWithError. The error object passed to that is

> Printing description of error:
>   ▿ Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x61000005b270 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.212.128:8088/login, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.212.128:8088/login, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.})

Here is what happens on the command line. A custom auth header is required, so the response is supposed to be 401.

```
mlilback@Morticia$curl -vi https://rc2dev.rc2.io:8443/login
*   Trying 192.168.212.128...
* Connected to rc2dev.rc2.io (192.168.212.128) port 8443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate: Rc2Stat
> GET /login HTTP/1.1
> Host: rc2dev.rc2.io:8443
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: Fri, 18 Mar 2016 10:06:53 GMT
Date: Fri, 18 Mar 2016 10:06:53 GMT
< Content-Length: 13
Content-Length: 13

< 
unauthorized
* Connection #0 to host rc2dev.rc2.io left intact
mlilback@Morticia$nscurl --verbose https://rc2dev.rc2.io:8443/login
unauthorized
```

Enabling CFNetworkDiagnostics doesn't return anything useful except the same error I got from the debugger.

As to ATS, my info.plist includes:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

I'm at a total loss to what the problem could be. Any ideas?

Comment: I had a similar problem today and in my case it turned out that my personal firewall blocked the connections of the app. As it blocks on a per app basis, other apps could access the address just fine (curl for example). Once I completely disabled that software, everything worked well. I don't know, maybe that info is somehow useful for you so I just thought I share it with you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent hours on that issue and couldn't find any reason why I receive the error described in the initial post. Turning off the firewall fixed it for me.